# Background position, margin-top?

Tags: css

I currently have my background set to top right as:

```
#thedivstatus {
    background-image: url("imagestatus.gif");
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

***BUT!*** I need to add a `margin-top:50px;` from where its rendering via above. Could anyone give me a suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Huh? You mean you need the background to stretch 50px before any content? That would be `padding-top`. Otherwise, your question makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I meant, I wanted the background image placed 50px downward from where default 'right top' css places it.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you mean you want the background image itself to be offset by 50 pixels from the top, like a background margin, then just switch out the `top` for `50px` and you're set.

```
#thedivstatus {
    background-image: url("imagestatus.gif");
    background-position: right 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you do percentages that way, too?

Comment: Well. It has only two options left and right. That is linked to X and Y axis. So if you want to change the value from the top, you need to change right to left.

Comment: simple and easy! Thanks a lot for this, very helpful!

Answer (score 13):

```
 background-image: url(/images/poster.png);
 background-position: center;
 background-position-y: 50px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

working in Navbar adding an image in GrapesJs.Display Image in Split

```
.gjs-block-navbar1{
width: 100%;
height:auto;
background-image: url("./assets/images/navbar/navbar-1.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center 0px;
background-size:cover;
}
```

[image]

> In Sidebar image fix to display center and clear

Answer (score -3):

```
#div-name

{

  background-image: url('../images/background-art-main.jpg');
  background-position: top right 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp background position only takes two values, x and y

Comment: Unless you use calc-- then you can use a percentage and an offset:

background-position: calc(50% + 10px) 50%