# Is there a way to apply margin and/or padding when applying multiple background images css

Tags: html, css

So here is my css:

```
.hero-scent_microban_bkgrnd {
        height: 749px;
        margin-top: -60px;
        background-image: url(../img/home/bg_microban_overlay1.png),
        url(../img/home/bg_hero_microban_bkgrnd.png);
        background-size: 85%, 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-position: center, center;
            
      }
```

What I would like to do is apply the margins or the padding for the backgrounds separately.

Comment: Have you tried setting pixels with `background-position` ? Something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743717/background-position-margin-top)

Comment: @DeusDev no i haven't. Let me try that. I know I could most likely just use one background and then put the other image in a DIV, but that doesn't seem to be as elegant when the screen is reponsive. but, I will try this!! thank you